# Membership having problems creating users from different application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I have 2 applications (MVC) like this :

Website

and

Admininistration

In each of them, I'm using asp.net membership provider (using mysql) like this :

Website web.config

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="mySqlConnectionString" applicationName="Website" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider" hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" autogenerateschema="false" 
              type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" 
              connectionStringName="mySqlConnectionString" 
              enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
              enablePasswordReset="true" 
              requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
              applicationName="Website" 
              requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
              passwordFormat="Hashed" 
              maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="25" 
              minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
              minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
              passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
              passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
```

Adminitration web.config

```
  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="mySqlConnectionString" applicationName="Administration" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
  <membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider" hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" autogenerateschema="true" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="mySqlConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="Glocalapps" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
  <profile defaultProvider="MySqlProfileProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="mySqlConnectionString" applicationName="Administration" />
    </providers>
  </profile>
```

Both use same connection string.

Everything works without a problem, I can register and login on both sites and users are created perfectly within it's own application.

I'm trying to implement a Create User from the Administration web application for the Website application like this :

```
Membership.ApplicationName = "Website";
var membership = Membership.CreateUser(username, password);
```

this does create the user without a problem, but if I try to log in from the website application, it returns a password error. I did testing and this is indeed a password error. (if i copy another hash/salt from other user created on the website I can then login with this new created user, so the user is created OK, but for some reason the password is not recognized when the user is created from the Administration application)

Anyone has already faced this problem or have any idea on why is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that on one config I have this :

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider" hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
```

while the other application

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
```

adding the `hashAlgorithType` solved the issue. Application name **CAN** be changed on runtime.